Azure Synapse - Output rows less then preview
I'm trying to create a data flow to merge some data.
Nothing super complex but when I run the data flow the row returned in the excel file are less then the preview data (the number rows of the preview is correct)
I load some JSON files as sources.
I've tried to switch to single partition but no luck with that, I alwasy get 29 rows on 78 total in my csv file.

Could you please help me resolving this issue?
To load all the data sources, merge and create a csv file.
Data preview has the correct number of rows but the output has less rows.

There was a static value for the start date in the pipeline.
Please be careful with local parameters (for the pipeline) and action parameters (that sits under action itself).
